# Canon PIXMA MG6320 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, printing, canon, pixma

I recently got a Canon PIXMA MG6320 printer and I love it, but I can't seem to get it to print on Ubuntu 12.10. I went through the standard setup, and it connected fine, until time came to print. I looked online for drivers, but there were none for Ubuntu or Linux in general.

Thanks in advance,

Rain

Answer (score 4):

This site is from Canon Australia and it has both scan and print drivers for Canon MG6300 series printers. For Ubuntu choose the Debian drivers.

[MG6360 printer driver download page - Australia](https://www.canon.com.au/printers/pixma-mg3660/support)

[MG6340 printer driver download page - UK](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg6340.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit))

It has been my experience that Canon USA doesn't support Linux, but often you can find suitable Linux drivers at other Canon locations.

Answer (score 1):

I installed those drivers and it still did not print.

I found this tip somewhere else.

```
$ cnijnetprn --search auto
```

It returned this...

```
network cnijnet:/18-0C-AC-C8-67-F7 "Canon MG6300 series" "Canon-MG6300-series_18-0C-AC-C8-67-F7"
```

Then I used lpadmin, entering the printer name, ppd file and the MAC address from above.

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p canonmg6320 -P canonmg6300.ppd -v cnijnet:/18-0C-AC-C8-67-F7 -E
```

I had to cd to where the *.pdd files are located (or enter the full path).

After that a new printer was listed as available, with the name canonmg6320. A test page worked.

The test page said that the driver was CNMG6300.PPD